# How to include different languages in a PHP website?

Tags: php

in a website I am creating I want to include several languages.

Below is how I identify what language should I show.

```
    <?php
    $pagename = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
       if (strpos($pagename,'?en') !== false) 
         {
            echo 'english';
here is when I have to include a language template file for english language.
         }
    ?>
```

My goal is to include language template files instead of duplicating all of my websites for any language.

So what I think about it, is for example in `index.php` the variable will be the same for all languages, but the content will be changed.

```
<div id="main">
<?php echo $main_description; ?>
</div>
```

How should I include a language file for this to work?

```
$main_description ="this is the main description written in english"
```

Comment: Have you tried googling something like `php localization`?

Comment: Have a look at `Gettext`: http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php

Comment: I had a good experience with PHP/GNU gettext (http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something similar to the if statement that you have and include the specific file with all the variables.

```
switch ($_GET['lang']) {
    case "en":
        include "lang/en.php";
        break;
    case "es":
        include "lang/es.php";
        break;
    default:
        include "lang/en.php";
}
```

But here, all of your strings will be in variables an you have to be careful not to use/overwrite those variables in the rest of your code.

[This page](http://www.mind-it.info/2010/02/22/a-simple-approach-to-localization-in-php/) offers a pretty simple and easy to follow example on how to do it JSON encoded language file that the script loads and finds the text you want and returns the translated text.

Comment: Thank you for this. I think I will use this solution for now, but I get this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BREAK`

Comment: Ah yes, the default case has no break statement. The lines should also end in semicolons. My bad, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a framework which supports internationalization if you're not to far along in development.

For example, Codeigniter has the [Language Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html)

Or you could just implement something similar to theirs.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably have to write up different languages for each template and just include that file instead of the English one.

If I could recommend, have you tried this for your website?
https://translate.google.com/manager/

Might make your job a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

The de-facto standard approach to internationalization is [GNU Gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) ([PHP bindings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php)).

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it w/ files, make a database like:

```
id               | en              | de             | es
---------------------------------------------------------------------
MAIN_DESCRIPTION | English desc .. | German desc .. | Spanish desc ..
MENU_1           | English des2 .. | German des2 .. | Spanish des2 ..
```

when you get the right code, just load the right table

```
if ( strpos( $pagename, '?en' ) !== false ) {
  $lang_code = 'en';
} elseif ( strpos( $pagename, '?de' ) !== false ) {
  $lang_code = 'de';
...
}

$query = "SELECT " . $lang_code . " FROM texts WHERE id = MAIN_DESCRIPTION";
```

etc ...

PS: Don't insert directly a variable inside the query, that will result in bad `query injection` attempts.